# Facebook FQL query to stream table for posts by user is returning just one post

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I'm posting to Facebook FQL the following query: `SELECT post_id, comments, message FROM stream WHERE source_id=me()` and its just returning one post. Whats going on? I thought it would send all of my posts. Is it correct to be using `source_id`?

** EDIT **
Do you think it has something to do with my subscription to an application? Im accessing the user from the application.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have read_stream permissions it sounds like you are only getting public posts.

> To read the stream table you need
>
> - read_stream permissions for all posts that the current session user is
>     able to view
> - read_insights permissions to see post impressions for any
>     posts made by a Page owned by the current session user

Comment: OK So I did this and it actually aggregated a few more posts, however it does not contain ALL the posts and Im trying to aggregate data for analytics metrics and I need to access ALL of the users posts. Is there a limit natively in FQL? I dont understand why its only returning a few posts.

Comment: I found this answer: http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/14268907/ and it states that i can get the last 50 posts or thirty days. is there no way to get ALL of the users posts from birth? Also, its not even doing what that answer states. its sending me back alot fewer than 50 or the past thirty days

Comment: Do you think it has something to do with my subscription to an application? Im accessing the user from the application

Comment: @jkushner that's correct, stream only goes back so far. Consider using /me/home for news feed or /me/posts for yourself and then paginate